# CLLocationManager won't stop updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

Here is my code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    // SETUP THE LOCATION MANAGER. 
    self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.locManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locManager.delegate release];
}
```

When the View Controller exits the CLLocationManager arrow logo in the top right corner is still showing. This is both on iOS 4.3 and 5.0. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system indicates the location badge on any app that has used Core Location in last hour or so.

Comment: Really? Why would it do that? Any more info or resources on this?

Comment: @Eric To allow users to know which app queried their locations.  If the icon was up for only a sec, users wouldn't have time to acknowledge it.

Comment: The badge on the status bar will disappear within a few seconds when location services are no longer active (system-wide). The purple arrow next to your app in Settings->Privacy->Location Services will turn grey within a couple of minutes of your app ceasing to use location services (just tested it) and remain grey for 24 hours after last use.

Answer (score 0):

The purple arrow should disappear as soon as you call:

```
[self.locManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

While allocating your locManager, you need not call self.locManager. That will bump up the retain count to 2. Instead use:

```
locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

Also, put a breakpoint in your viewWillDisappear: method and make sure it does get called. Also, set the delegate to nil at the end. 
After following these points, your code shall work.
The purple arrow is for Location Services and consumes battery heavily. Make sure the arrow disappears as soon as you call stopUpdatingLocation: